# HTML showing after PHP code in <img> tag

Tags: php, images

I am trying to display a page featured image. Every time I use the img tag,the text after the php code (" class="headshot" >) displays below the picture on the website. See picture screenshot of picture below 
[image]

```
<div class="bio-picture">
    <img url="<?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>" class="headshot">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `the_post_thubmnail()` outputs an `<img>` tag. So the result of your code will be something like this:

```
<div class="bio-picture">
    <img url="<img src="thumbnail/image/url.jpg" class="wp-post-image attachment-full">" class="headshot">
</div>
```

Your screenshot is how the browser has chosen to handle that broken HTML.

If you want to output the post thumbnail `<img>` with a custom class, use this:

```
<div class="bio-picture">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'headshot' ) );?>
</div>
```

Also, please note that the correct attribute for the `img` tag's URl is not `url`, it's `src`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm learning as I go and it's normally a simple answer.